# Is there any way to import and export excel 2010 file in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xlsx

I need to use Rails to handle excel

I wonder is there any way to handle 2010 version excel file, say .xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

Try the spreadsheet gem, worked well for me.

http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet

Comment: it works for 2007...I want to handle xlsx..but Spreadsheet seems not to support 2010...